# Branch not tracking Google Advertising Id

Tags: android, branch.io, google-advertising-id

I am using Branch.io in my project. I am not able to see the Google Advertising Id tracking with any of their events (install/open/click).  I have added play-service-ads dependency as per their [doc](https://docs.branch.io/apps/android-launch/#submitting-to-the-play-store).

**Note: I am testing in a debug build.**

- Why Branch is not tracking advertising id?
- Will it be tracked in play store build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When integrating the SDKs, it's often useful to use **setDebug** to verify that your app is able to communicate with Branch servers, and is receiving deep link data. Please use live mode for testing google ad id. Also make sure following code is not present in your app build:

```
Branch.enableDebugMode();
```

If you still face any issue reach out to our super helpful support team at support@branch.io.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please call the following line right after you instantiate Branch in your 
Application’s onCreate() or Activity’s onCreate() (and before you call initSession)

mTracker = sAnalytics.newTracker("UA-XXXXXXXX-1");

String client_id = mTracker.get("&cid");
Branch.getInstance().setRequestMetadata("$google_analytics_client_id",client_id);
```